# Which areas are suitable for low level characters at the beginning?

Tags: fallout-4

I'm still pretty much at the start of the game, level 6 currently and I visited Diamond City briefly. I'm exploring the map randomly right now, but I keep running into pretty high-level enemies.

Are there some rough guidelines on which areas of the map are appropriate for low level characters? I'd appreciate avoiding any spoilers, I'm just looking for a rough idea on which directions and locations I should explore at the beginning.

Comment: (not an answer as I only played 1 hour) in FO3 and F:NV  I usually went in concentric circles around the starting Vault and surrounding areas.

Comment: @kalina I've been wondering about this, how did you managed to keep your radiation down before getting to diamond city? By level 7, I had no choice but to go to the city because half my hp as gone due to radiation and I hadn't found a single rad-away or clinic anywhere.

Comment: One of the "wait screen tips" says that things generally get tougher the further south you go.

Comment: @CoqPwner I'm only level 4, I just did the Minuteman quest and went to the USAF science station and I've already found 3 radaways

Answer (score 2):

I have had the mission to go to Diamond City for a while (you get it quite early on) but I have put off going there yet - I'm getting pretty close now just from completing all of the other missions along the way. Here are the places I've been so far:

[image: placesIhavebeen]

As commented by Max, generally I work my way out from the starting point in circles exploring. Generally (excluding legendary enemies) everything up to the road in both directions from Sanctuary should be OK at low level.

Answer (score 2):

If you're low-level, a general rule of thumb is to stay to the north. While enemies will generally scale with you, you will encounter far more "tough" enemies like Deathclaws and Super Mutants as you move further south.